# Android 4.3 adbd: is it possible to password protect root access?

Tags: android, security, adb, daemon

I know this is handled much better in AOSP7 and even offers the user the toggle for turning debugging off at a network and more general level. But 4.3 does not seem to allow that.
I want to be able to password protect an adb root command made over a network. Does anyone have any inkling on how this could be achieved?

Thanks ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In android you'll have root access using the "su" which actually is an program that start another programs with a different user ID (user id 0 which is the root user id). You can intercept su requests by replacing su program in /sbin/su with any custom su version.

This post defienetly would help you :

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2974/what-is-the-default-android-root-password

Btw the su binary executable path in your android device may differ depend on the tool you used for rooting your device.

It may be in one the following paths:

1- /sbin/su

2-/system/xbin/su

3-/system/bin/su

To find where is your su file type this in adb shell:

```
   Which su
```

You can change the su source code (c++ i think) in a way that every access needs a password. Actually you can do anything using c++. You can even write your own su binary but for doing this you need to know what su really does you can even write su with bash scripting rather than c++.

A link for a sample working su source code:

https://github.com/ChainsDD/su-binary

Comment: Seems like a logical answer, thank you for the link. However, I cant find any trace of an 'su' in the sbin. The device is connected to a network via ethernet so i can gain access simply with the ip address.

Comment: You must use root access to see su through adb shell.

Comment: adb root
adb shell
cd /sbin
ls
Here I have adbd, watchdogd and ueventd

Comment: Check these two paths: system/bin/ and system/sbin  . Let me know if you find that.

Comment: I have a system/bin but no system/sbin. 
There is no 'su' in system/bin either

Comment: I have found 'su' in system/xbin

Comment: Also in some devices its in /system/xbin/su

Comment: You cant change su binary code though cuz its been unreadable. But you can see the source here : https://github.com/ChainsDD/su-binary

Comment: THis does not apply to a user though does it?

Comment: The issue isnt with apps requesting root access, what I want to stop is certain people being able to access root via the network.

Comment: You can change the su source code (c++ i think) in a way that every access needs a password. Actually you can do anything using c++. You can even write your own su binary but for doing this you need to know what su really does you can even write su with bash scripting rather than c++.